# Where's the functional functions that manipulate lists and maps in jdk8

Tags: functional-programming, java-8

I've downloaded JDK8.0 early access release few days ago (file name: `jdk-8-ea-bin-b82-linux-x64-21_mar_2013.tar.gz`)

I can find `java.util.function` package. (only contains Interfaces), and it is do lambda perfectly. (OK)

But, What I search for but couldn't find is the list/map manipulations functions (`forEach`, `filter`, `map`, ...etc).

So tutorials says I will find in `java.util.List` interface, and others refers to non-existed `java.util.Stream` class. But I Couldn't find any new methods in the interface, nor could find this new class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply, the build version `jdk-8-ea-bin-b82` is missing the new Java 8 methods in the `Iterable` interface. All build versions between at least 82 and 87 are missing the methods. (See this related albeit unanswered [early access post](https://www.java.net/forum/topic/jdk/java-se-snapshots-project-feedback/basic-foreach-not-compiling)). Recent releases such as build 91 contain the new methods.

Comment: So, What about `java.util.streams` package?

Comment: Don't you mean `java.util.stream`? This exists in b91